# Create shapefiles with GDAL and Android studio

Tags: gdal, utm

Because in GDAL when creating shapefiles with spatial reference WGS84_UTM_zone_18S, I get a warning of,

> The added layers have an extension that is not consistent with the associated spatial reference information

but that doesn't happen when I change it to WGS84_UTM_zone_18N.

Comment: 18S is Southern hemisphere https://epsg.io/32718 18N is northern hemisphere https://epsg.io/32618

Comment: MY SPACE REFERENCE IS LIKE THIS:
val spatialReference = SpatialReference()
spatialReference.ImportFromProj4("+proj=utm +zone=18 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs");
I CREATE IT WITH ETSA REFERENCES THE SHAPE FILES, BUT IT SENDS ME THAT WARNING BUT THAT DOES NOT HAPPEN WITH 18N

Comment: If possible, make a complete Python test case that can be used for re-producing the issue.